# How to pay Australian GST for an overseas journal fee?

Tags: australia, gst, swift

I have to pay open access publication fees for a journal in Hong Kong. The payment is supposed to be transferred via swift.

Apparently, according to [new rules](https://www.finder.com.au/australian-gst-changes-international-shopping), I should pay GST for this service (whether it is fair or unfair).

If it was a commodity from ebay, I would say the website would sort out everything. However, in this case, I have no idea how the GST should be paid.

Comment: Customers have never had to pay the GST themselves. This should be between the journal and the ATO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obligation to pay GST is on the business selling a good or service, not on the consumer, so you're in the clear

The ATO will need to take this up with the Journal if they want to collect

For physical goods there is a chance that customs will add the 10% at the border and ask the sender to pay before they will release the package for delivery. In the case of a digital good or service, they literally can't enforce it